# How to launch an external application on BN_CLICKED?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-ce

I'm fairly new to Windows programming. I'm doing a simple launcher app for WinCE using VC++ (not MFC). So far I've created the basic interface and buttons and stuff. I just wanted to know the best way to launch an external application when the user clicks the button (on BN_CLICKED).

I found some methods such as ShellExecute, CreateProcess and others. But I couldn't get it to work (yet?). Any suitable reference or simple example on this?

Comment: ShellExecute/CreateProcess should work, could you possibly show your code (which uses those functions)? That way we can see what you may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The question don't matter that it happens inside the event of a button click, but...

[ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) is a good way to start programs (and the default program for any other type of files) in Windows, but use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) if you need a return code, or if you need the ability to wait for the program to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found a working example on MSDN - a comment by a user.
For anyone interested, you can go to this [CreateProcess() article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) and scroll down to a comment entitled "Working code for creating two processes "p1.exe" and "p2.exe" using CreateProcess() Method"

Thanks!